# is it possible to share a custom theme between a project and an .aar library?

Tags: android, themes, libraries, aar

I have a custom theme in my project which contain a button with a specific color and I want my library's button use this theme. 
Is it possible? And if yes how can I proceed?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, maybe provide an example?

Comment: I have add an example, if you need more information, please says me

Comment: How is the color of the button in the library determined? Is there a custom XML attribute that set the color?

Comment: the theme and the color are in the project, not in the library

Comment: That's not what i asked. Does your library define an XML attribute that the button uses to determine its color? These attributes can be used in your main project when you write your layout files.

Comment: no, if possible, I want there are no or not a lot of modification in the main project