# Can I apply a theme to an activity from the aar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-theme

We ship an aar to our customer. We are facing a problem as we use an action bar in one of our activities and the customer has his theme set to:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Now this is causing a problem as the app crashes. Is it possible for the customer to add an entry in their manifest for our activity and set its theme to what we suggest?

Comment: please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185254/is-it-possible-to-share-a-custom-theme-between-a-project-and-an-aar-library

Comment: Thats not the same question, also there is no answer there in the question.

Comment: Did you tried to set theme to your activity into aar?

Comment: No we dont specify a theme in our AAR.